# Lifecycle of Objects in JavaScript vs Markup

Tags: javascript, html, object-lifetime

Ok peep's I've recently been learning about **custom elements** ie: `<x-foo>`.

I found that they have **lifecycle callbacks**, a series of *listeners* that can be attached to the element in order to further process it relative to its' current stage ie:

> - Created
> - Attached
> - Detached
> - Attribute Changed

eg:

```
var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

proto.createdCallback = function() {...};
proto.attachedCallback = function() {...};

var XFoo = document.registerElement('x-foo', {prototype: proto});

elm = new XFoo();
par.appendChild(elm);
```

### My Question...

These callbacks seem to be specific to **custom elements**. So how do I achieve a similar result for standard/non-custom elements. ie:

```
var proto = HTMLDivElement.prototype;

proto.createdCallback = function() {...};
proto.attachedCallback = function() {...};

div = document.cerateElement('div');
par.appendChild(elm);
```

Comment: Web Components browser support is also sketchy right now, so if this is for production code, consider using a MutationObserver to monitor changes to the DOM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When are MutationObserver callbacks fired?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564617/when-are-mutationobserver-callbacks-fired)